# Regex to select a phone number of 10 digits but be invalid if the string contains more than 10 digits?

Tags: regex

So far I have `(\+\d{{0-9}}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}` which hits all my test cases except for one (number 6 should be invalid).

```
=> 1 VALID   - 2437284712
=> 2 VALID   - (723)728-2020
=> 3 VALID   - 243 728 4712
=> 4 VALID   - (900)8593019

=> 5 INVALID - 24372847
=> 6 VALID   - (723)728-20201
=> 7 INVALID - 243 78 4712
=> 8 INVALID - (800)CITYLINE
```

[image]
source: debuggex.com

**How can I make this regex be invalid for test case #6 when it contains 11 digits?**

Comment: Add anchors `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, otherwise you are just searching for the match anywhere in the string.

Comment: Out of curiosity, the question is `How can I make this regex be invalid for test case #6 when it contains 11 digits?` but the accepted answer does not solve that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add start and end anchors and solve the problem, yet I doubt that your expression might be what you might have in mind, since it would pass `+0{{0-9}} 2437284712`:

```
^(\+\d{{0-9}}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3BKUXO/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string, to make  test case #6 pass you could match either 4 or 5 digits by extending the quantifier at the end with `?\d{4,5}$` to match 4 or 5 digits.

That would then also match 11 digits in a row if that is allowed.

```
^(\+\d{{0-9}}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqX6IY/1)

Another option is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to specifically match that exact pattern with 5 digits at the end to keep your original matches and add one extra pattern:

```
^(?:(\+\d{{0-9}}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{5})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqX6IY/2)